# How to put a company logo picture beside each experience in a latex resume?

Tags: tables, floats, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

I come across a resume online and wonder how to format correctly of putting a company logo picture beside each experience as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: compang logo beside experience]

The template used is the well-known [res.cls](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/resume/res.cls) class by Michael DeCorte.

The normal formatting without logo is as below:

```
% Professional Experience
\section{\mysidestyle Professional\\Experience}
\textbf{Software Engineer} \hfill \textbf{04.2016 - present} \\
Contactor at Google ATAP, Mountain View, CA, USA
Working on .....
```

My guess is that it uses a tabular to separately display the logo and description in two columns, however, I have the problem to align the logo to center vertically and horizontally.

```
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{} p{0.5in} p{4.5in} @{}}
    \includegraphics[width=0.4in, height=0.4in]{logo.png} &
    \textbf{Software Engineer} \hfill \textbf{04.2016 - present} \newline
    Contactor at Google ATAP, Mountain View, CA, USA
    Working on .....
\end{tabular}
```

How could I achieve the effect I want?

Comment: https://twitter.com/templateGundar/status/777413569612812289

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/337432/1952

Comment: You can use an image in the optional argument to `\item` (in a `\itemize` environment using `\includegraphics`.  In `moderncv` you could use `\renewcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\includegraphics...}` paired with a `cvlistitem`

Comment: Thanks @ChrisH. I will try that out if I use `moderncv` at a later date.

Answer (score 1):

The image would centre horizontally if you used `c` instead of `p{0.5in}` for that column and to centre vertically you can use

```
\raisebox{-.5\height}{\includegraphics[width=0.4in, height=0.4in]{logo.png}}
```

sometimes some value other than  exactly `.5` looks better depending on visual effects of the white space in the image and the shape of the adjacent paragraph, just adjust by eye to fit what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried your code however it doesn't perfectly achieve the format in the picture. When I change `p{0.5in}` to `c` and add the `\raisebox{-.5\height}{...}`, the logo starts to align horizontally in the middle of the column, however, I need to manually adjust `.5` for each paragraph to make it look centred vertically. Is there any more elegant way to centre it vertically?

Comment: I also tried to change all `p{*in}` to `m{*in}` and add `\centering` in front of `includegraphics`. It can automatically centre vertically this way, however, it doesn't look centered horizontally perfectly. Any suggestion?

Comment: @J.A.  `\centering` would centre it if the specified width to `m` is greater than the width of the image.

Comment: thank you for pointing this out! When I use it that way, the image always looks a little to the left. Not sure why? Is this the complexity of Latex? You seem to be an expert of Latex. I am relative new to latex and this is the first document I write in latex. But I do start to enjoy the advantage brought by Latex.

Comment: @J.A. (it's my code you are discussing:-) impossible to say why it doesn't look centred (and this site really doesn't work with followup questions in comments) often with images you need to adjust the space "by eye" as the visual effect can be influenced by the shape of the image if it doesn't appear as a rectangular block or has more white space on one side within the image itself.

Comment: True, it is not very convenient to try code and see effects right away on this site. Maybe I can create some test codes on Overleaf for easy comments and collaboration. I will do some test at a later date and send you @David the link if you don't mind.